# Not able to modify the contents of my local drives

Tags: permissions

I'm a new in Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it's a dual boot and also the partitions are created by Windows 10 (which is the other OS in my Laptop-PC) and the file type is NTFS.

I'm not able to create/rename/cut/paste my folders in my local drives. After some research I found out that it's a permission issue. The permission of these belongs to root.

I have tried all the different ways I can find in the askubuntu.com and other websites but still of no use.

I have tried:

1. `sudo chown user:user`
   to which output gives:`chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/STUDY': Read-only file system`
2. `chown -R $USER: /path/to/files`
   to which output gives: `chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/STUDY': Read-only file system`
3. `sudo chmod 755 /media/$USER/"partition name"`
   to which output gives:`chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/STUDY': Read-only file system`

and many other but still same results.

And yes, it is happening from since the day I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my PC. Accidentally (or so I presume), one day I got all the permission to modify the folder content but after I restart my PC everything goes back to READ-ONLY permission. And I didn't understood what's happened.

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/STUDY': Read-only file system

Answer (score 1):

By default, ntfs ("Windows") partitions (which show as drive letters under Windows) are not mounted automatically. You can however mount them by clicking the icon of the volume that appears in the left column of Files. Mounted this way, ntfs volumes are by default readable and writable by the user that mounted the volume.

That your volume is apparently mounted as read-only may indicate that *the volume is not "clean"*, i.e., it was not properly closed before. In order to prevent damage, Linux will refuse to mount such a volume with write permissions.

That an ntfs ("Windows") volume is not clean can result from Windows being setup for *fast start*. With that setting, Windows does not close all file systems and files as one of the strategies to resume quicker on a subsequent setup. However, if you need to use the ntfs volumes while Windows is shut down, you will need to 1) disable fast-start in MS Windows and 2) secure that you shut Windows fully down (no hibernate!) before starting up Linux.

Thus, to solve your issue,

1. Boot into Windows
2. Disable "Fast Start" (Consult the manual of your Windows operating system to see how this is changed)
3. Use the Windows drive checking tools to check the integrity of the ntfs partition and repair possible issues

After this one-time action, make sure to always shut down Windows completely before accessing the volume under Linux.

It is a good habit to regularly perform 3. while you are in Windows. While Linux can work very well with an ntfs formatted partition, it is only MS Windows that is fully capable of checking and repairing such file system.